# Get a value based on last and current row according to a group of conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get a Quantity value in a Upgrade column based on the calculation condition on the column Type, then compare to previous year for different column Group.  I am using SQL Server 2012.

The condition to get the Quantity value for Upgrade column is:

```
if previous t1 in Quantity >0 and 
(current year t2 in Quantity - previous year t1 in Quantity )>= 0,
then  
 upgrade = previous year t1 in Quantity  
 else if    
 previous year t1 in Quantity > 0 and current year t2 in Quantity - previous year t1 in Quantity <0
  then   
update =  current year t2 in Quantity
```

The values in Group, Year, Type, Quantity are in a table.  The desired output value are in the column Upgrade (The values in Upgrade column are the output  results I need to have ).

```
Group Year Type Quantity   Upgrade
a     2013  t1  2   
a     2014  t1  1
a     2014  t2  3          2
a     2015  t1  5
a     2015  t2  10
a     2016  t1  6
a     2016  t2  4          4
a     2017  t2  7          6
b     2013  t1  3
b     2014  t2  5          3
b     2015  t2  9
b     2016  t1  4
b     2016  t2  7
c     2012  t1  4
c     2012  t2  5
c     2013  t1  5
c     2013  t2  6          4
c     2014  t2  1          1
```

Here is the the table for creating the data for query to against to

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable](
[MyGroup] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[MyYear] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[Type] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[Quantity] [int] NULL
)


Insert into MyTable (MyGroup, MyYear, Type, Quantity) 
 values
('a',   '2013', 't1',   '2'),
('a',   '2014', 't1',   '1'),
('a',   '2014', 't2',   '3'),
('a',   '2015', 't1',   '5'),
('a',   '2015', 't2',   '10'),
('a',   '2016', 't1',   '6'),
('a',   '2016', 't2',   '4'),
('a',   '2017', 't2',   '7'),
('b',   '2013', 't1',   '3'),
('b',   '2014', 't2',   '5'),
('b',   '2015', 't2',   '9'),
('b',   '2016', 't1',   '4'),
('b',   '2016', 't2',   '7'),
('c',   '2012', 't1',   '4'),
('c',   '2012', 't2',   '5'),
('c',   '2013', 't1',   '2'),
('c',   '2013', 't2',   '6'),
('c',   '2014', 't2',   '1');
```

Comment: Can you turn this into something we can query against? sqlfiddle.com would be a good choice. Then if you could also post the desired output from the sample data that would help. One last question, what version of sql server are you using? The query might be vastly different depending on which version you have since there are some great improvements for this sort of thing in the more recent versions.

Comment: I have updated my question based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if I understood you correctly, you can do this:

```
SELECT t.*,
       CASE WHEN s.quantity is null then null 
           ELSE CASE WHEN s.quantity > 0 and t.quantity - s.quantity > 0 then s.quantity
               ELSE CASE WHEN s.quantity > 0 and t.quantity - s.quantity < 0 then t.quantity end end end as 'UPGRADE'
from YourTable t
LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTable s ON(t.group = s.group and t.year = s.year-1 
                               AND t.type = 't2' and s.type = 't1')
```

This basically does what you want by using CASE expression, which is similar to if,elseif,else..

Comment: Hi sagi, thank you very much for your quick response.  Based on Sean's suggestion, I have added code to generate data for the table and clarify the output column.  I ran your code, but I didn't get the result I want to see in Upgrade column (see my table above).

Comment: I just made a very minor change ( might be just your typo), t.MyYear -1 = s.MyYear.  The result is correct.  I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Yes my mistake , I was tired after work so I didn't notice that.. No problem @SteveJ

Comment: I have a new condition

Comment: I have a new - third condition .....
  Case When....
    ELSE CASE WHEN previous year t1 in Quantity > 0 and current year t1 in Quantity - previous year t1 in Quantity = 0 then 0....
Now it needs to use current year t1 in Quantity, the join on t.type = 't2' and s.type = 't1'  is not true anymore.  What should I do?

Comment: Please open a new question.. @stevej